# A 3x3 matrix with 1 real eigenvalue.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Does there exist a non-diagonalizable 3x3 matrix that has precisely 1 real eigenvalue and a multiplicity of 1? When it comes to multiplicity I'm trying to find a matrix that would give me something like $(\lambda-1)^3$ as the eigenvalue. This factors down to $\lambda^3 - 3\lambda^2+3\lambda-1$ so you could say the multiplicity is 3 but you can also say that it only has 1 real root. So could I use this to find a non-diagonalizable 3x3 matrix with only 1 eigenvalue. So would such a matrix exist?

Comment: For one real eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity 1, you'd have a characteristic polynomial of $(\lambda-a)(\lambda^2+b\lambda +c)$ where the quadratic $(\lambda^2+b\lambda +c)$ is irreducible (i.e. it has no real roots).  Example: $(\lambda -1)(\lambda^2+\lambda+1)$.

Comment: non-daigonazable?  you are adding additional criteria.

Comment: Would it make a difference?

Comment: I have given you an example of a daigonalizable matrix with one real eigenvalue.

Comment: I thought that a matrix can't be diagonalizable if the number of eigenvalues does not equal the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: Then look at the example I have provided and see if you can figure out where your intuition is failing you.

Comment: I still don't understand. How can that matrix still be diagonalizable if there's only 1 eigenvalue?

Comment: Wait...are you using complex numbers? I haven't learned complex numbers and have no idea how they work. Anyway, so does there exist a non daigonalizable matrix with only 1 real eigenvalue?

Comment: @davidmah The question about matrices with only one real eigenvalue suggests that others are not real, which does assume some knowledge of complex numbers. If your matrix is real then no, if it can be complex then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the matrix to be real, one real eigenvalue of multiplicity one leaves the only possibility for other two to be nonreal and complex conjugate. Thus all three eigenvalues are different, and the matrix must be diagonalizable.

If the matrix can be complex then it is possible to find a non-diagonalizable matrix with the only real eigenvalue of multiplicity one, for example
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & i & 1\\
0 & 0 & i
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I forgot to add an important detail. It also has to be non-diagonalizable.

Comment: @davidmah Sorry for being unclear. I was talking about non-diagonalizable matrices too (edited).

Comment: So then it's not possible without complex numbers?

Comment: @davidmah For real matrices it is not possible (however, the diagonalization is going to be complex).

Answer (score 4):

Sure

\begin{bmatrix} 0&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}

has one real eigenvalue of multiplicity 1.

Answer (score 1):

For example

$$\begin{pmatrix}x&1&0\\0&x&1\\0&0&x\end{pmatrix}$$

has one unique eigenvalue $\;x\;$ of algebraic multiplicity $\;3\;$ and *geometric multiplicity* $\;1\;$ (if this is what you meant) , for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ .